# Mysql Database in java: On the same date, there should not be the same ID Number?

Tags: java, mysql

There is a table with columns ID Number and date, ..

**The problem:** how to be on the same date may not have the same ID Number.
Example: ID Number 001 has been entering data in the 29th, then when the date of the ID Number 001 to conduct a second input on the same day then it is not allowed.
But when a different date, ID Number should have the same, ..

Help me please :(

Comment: Your question is not so clear: do you need to create a constraint that matches your example ? or maybe you need to insert another record with the same date and id ? what is your PK ? do you get some errors ? and how does `java` take place in your question ?

Comment: I have a table tb_teach with columns ID as a primary key. then there is also a table tb_present with columns ID as a forign key that references the ID in the table tb_teach. I do not want any teacher Presence on the same date. but if he's Presence at different dates, he can do it. so essentially, in the ID column should have the same id as long as the dates differ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harysay, can you provide more examples?  I'm not sure what you're looking to do here.

If you make an ID and Date your Primary Keys, that will make it so that only one row with that exact data combination can exist in that table.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I have a table tb_teach with columns ID as a primary key. then there is also a table tb_present with columns ID as a forign key that references the ID in the table tb_teach. I do not want any teacher Presence on the same date. but if he's Presence at different dates, he can do it.
so essentially, in the ID column should have the same id as long as the dates differ

Comment: Make ID and Date Primary Keys in tb_teach.  That way it won't allow duplicates of BOTH fields being the same.

Answer (score 1):

Set a UNIQUE KEY in your table.

Comment: Which column should I make it unique?

sorry i still do not know much about programming and database, please enlightenment